# Issue with inserting rows automatically and then referencing in another tab

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

I am using Zapier to insert external content into a Google Spreadsheet tab automatically and it appears to insert a row directly under the last non-empty row rather than replacing the content in the next empty row.

So if row 7 was the last row, Zapier inserts a new row under 7 and the old row 8 becomes row 9.

I then have two other tabs, both viewable on the web (where the first isn't) that reference the content in the first tab but as new content is added, these references in the format of `data!a8` also gets moved.  If I use `data!$a$8` then I have to change 500 rows manually.

With or without coding, is there a way to allow Zapier to insert the rows but still reference that row automatically?

Comment: Make sure you read the docs https://zapier.com/help/google-docs/#how-setup-your-google-spreadsheet-work-zapier

It says you can't have any blank rows in middle of sheet.  Also does Zapier insert any scripts into the Google sheets. Click tools, script editor and if there is any code there, please share it.

You may also wish to look at NAMED RANGES as a solution also.
More info can be found here.  https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175

Comment: Thanks @Munkey, Zapier just inserts new records via oAuth (no added scripting) . I am now firing a script on onChange function that does the trick and after a lot of reading, scripting appears to be the only way. I will post an improved version of the code shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those attempting to do this without script, it appears it is not possible.

**Script**

1. Create a function like the one below. Note we are reading one sheet (AutomaticImport) and writing to the sheet WebData

   `function fncUpdateWebData() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
     sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AutomaticImport"),
     sheetWeb = ss.getSheetByName("WebData"),
     arrRides = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
     row,col,iOutputRow,strURL;`

   `iOutputRow = 2;
    for ( iRow = 1; iRow < arrRides.length; iRow++) {
        sheetWeb.getRange(iOutputRow,1).setValue(arrRides[iRow][5]); // date
        strURL = '=HYPERLINK("' + 'https://www.strava.com/activities/' + arrRides[iRow][7] + '","' + arrRides[iRow][8]  + '")';
        sheetWeb.getRange(iOutputRow,2).setValue(strURL); // start & link
        sheetWeb.getRange(iOutputRow,3).setValue(arrRides[iRow][4]); // Distance
        sheetWeb.getRange(iOutputRow,4).setValue(arrRides[iRow][0]); // Avg Speed

     iOutputRow++;
     }
   }`

   2. In **Resources/Current Project Triggers** and a new trigger and use your new function name, "from Spreadsheet" and select "onChange"

I hope his helps get you over the hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really, really late answer, but I was having the same issue and almost used the accepted solution before realizing there's a much better and easier way.

It's actually in the Zapier docs, right [here](https://zapier.com/help/common-problems-google-sheets-zapier/#rows-are-being-added-below-rows-with-formulas). The solution is to create two Google Sheets, one for Zapier and the other for your formulas. Hook Zapier up to the first sheet, and then use the [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) command to copy the necessary columns into the second sheet. Write your formulas in the second sheet, and you'll notice that the extra layer of indirection stops Google from rewriting them when a row is added to the source range!

Tl;dr: RTFM, as usual.